# java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host when trying to download file

Tags: java, exception, https, download

I'm trying to download a file using Java from a `https://` url and it keeps returning me this error:

> java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host

Here is the code I am using:

```
URL website = new URL(fileUrl);
File destinationFile = new File(toPath + returnFileNameFromUrl(fileUrl));
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(website, destinationFile);
```

I already tried doing like this:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = website.openStream();
     ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(inputStream);
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(toPath + returnFileNameFromUrl(fileUrl))) {
     fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
     }
```

But the result was the same.
What am I doing wrong?

I already checked, the URL is accesible from Chrome and the file exists.

Comment: What is `FileUtils` ? Standard Java has no such class.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Comment: There is no such thing as a https:\\ URL. Backslashes are not legal in URLs.

Comment: I corrected my post. But still, your answer has nothing to do with the subject.

Comment: @BogdanPușcașu It was a comment, not an answer, and your code cannot possibly execute correctly until that issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a bit lower level IO, it works for me without using third party dependency:

```
    URL fileUrl = new URL("http://link.to/a.file");
    File dest = new File("local.file");
    try(InputStream inputStream = fileUrl.openStream();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest)){
      byte[] buffer = new byte[64*1024];
      int readBytes;
      while((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length))!=-1){
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
      }
    }
```