# How to fix java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host when downloading a file

Tags: java, spring, download, ioexception

I'm trying to download a file in my application, but following exception is thrown:

> org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException:
>   java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host

I've read most of related questions on SO, specially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482585/java-io-ioexception-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-ho), but none helped me to get through this exception.

Code:

```
response.setContentType(mimeType);
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream responseOutPutStream = response.getOutputStream();

byte buffer[] = new byte[32 * 1024];
int bytes;
while ((bytes = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    responseOutPutStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
}
responseOutPutStream.flush();
inputStream.close();
responseOutPutStream.close();
```

`mimeType`is `application/octet-stream`

also, I implemented this code using `FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, responseOutPutStream);` but same result.

The request is sent from *ExtJS* application using `<a>` tag.

We tried to send a **Get** request via *Ajax*, but that didn't solve to problem.

There's almost 2 days since i'm searching and debugging, couldn't find any way to solve this problem.

how to fix this?

Best Regards

---

**EDIT:**

more information: I use Spring Boot as underlying framework and the code above is called in a controller class (annotated with `@Controller` annotation)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, thinking it was the response timeout I modified the implementation, replacing

> OutputStream responseOutPutStream = response.getOutputStream();

with

> try (PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter()) {
>   // your logic here
>   }

this way it works.

Comment: It doesn't explain why it could cause the exception. It could solve the problem, but explain why

Comment: response.getOutputStream () tries to make a bulk copy of the file and causes saturation of the resources of the response. While the response.getWriter () can divide the content and write it sequentially.